# convert for loop to foreach with index

Tags: c#, for-loop, foreach, tostring

I have this `ToString` method used to write out objects. I'm trying to convert the `for` loop to a `foreach` loop.
Without using LINQ.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

```
 public override string ToString()
 {
     StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
     output.AppendFormat("{0}", count);
     for (var index = 0; index < total; index++)
     {
         output.AppendFormat("{0}{1}{2} ", array[index], array[index].GetInfo,
                              string.Join(" ", array[index].Content(index)),
                            );
     }
     return output.ToString();
 }
```

Comment: why the close vote because this is too broad?

Comment: Okay, why the downvote? How in the world is this too broad?

Comment: A [mcve] would be useful here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a refactoring based on your current code.

```
public override string ToString() {
    var output = new StringBuilder();
    output.AppendFormat("{0}", count);
    var index = 0;
    foreach (var item in array) {
        if (item!=null) {
            output.AppendFormat("{0}{1}{2} ", item, item.GetInfo,
                              string.Join(" ", item.Content(index++)),
                            );
        }
    }
    return output.ToString();
}
```

Using linq you could perform the same with a indexed `Select` without directly calling the foreach which is used under the hood

```
public override string ToString() {
    var output = new StringBuilder();
    output.AppendFormat("{0}", count);
    array.Select((item, index) =>
        output.AppendFormat("{0}{1}{2} ", item, item.GetInfo,
                              string.Join(" ", item.Content(index)),
                            )
    );
    return output.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if I don't want to go through all the content of `array` beacuse some of it are null. Is it possible to break out of for each

Comment: You could filter to only take items that are not `null`. ie `array.Where(item => item!=null)`

Comment: ok then do your check in the foreach and you can either break or continue

Answer (score 2):

Technically, you can do something like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    output.Append(count);

    int index = 0;
    foreach (var item in array)
    {           
        output.Append($"{item}{item.GetInfo()}{string.Join(" ", item.Content(index))}");
        index++;
    }
    return output.ToString();
}
```

In any case, you're going to go for an `int index` anyway. Not so much of an help when it comes to moving it to foreach as per the `performance` goes.

You might try your own ForEach extension too if you really don't like writing incrementing indexes everywhere.

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static void ForEachWithIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Action<int, T> action)
    {
        // argument null checking omitted
        int i = 0;
        foreach (T item in sequence)
        {
            action(i, item);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Then your method would be even simpler but you'd have one more class to manage:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    output.Append(count);
    array.ForEachWithIndex((index, item) => output.Append($"{item}{item.GetInfo()}{string.Join("", item.Content(index))}"));
    return output.ToString();
}
```

And for readability, if you really are just putting strings side by side:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    output.Append(count);
    array.ForEachWithIndex((index, item) => output.Append(
        string.Concat(
            item, 
            item.GetInfo(), 
            string.Join("", item.Content(index))
            )));
    return output.ToString();
}
```

As `string.Concat` would be more appreciated performance wise anyway. Opt for the others if you need formatting.

Comment: Thanks man. This also works, but I have to accept the one that came in first.

Comment: It's perfectly fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what `total` and `count` are, you could refactor to something like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return count.ToString()
        + String.Join(" ",
            array.Select((x, n) => $"{x}{x.GetInfo}{String.Join(" ", x.Content(n))}"));
}
```

`String.Join` can often perform better than `StringBuilder` so it's not a bad alternative.

---

There you go. No LINQ required with this extension:

```
public static class Ex
{
    public static IEnumerable<R> Select<T, R>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, int, R> projection)
    {
        int index = 0;
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            yield return projection(item, index++);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: LINQ is not an option for me. Sorry, that was not stated in the question initially.

Comment: @hello - I've given you a non-LINQ solution.